# relative import for python33

Tags: python, import

I was trying to do some coding practice with python. And here's my structure

```
mydir/
  template.py
  problem1/
    solution.py
  problem2/
    solution.py
```

I'd like to write some general-used staff in template.py and import them in solution.py in both problem1 and problem2 and maybe the problems afterwards.

What should I do to make this possible.
  I was once trying to do this in solution.py

```
from .. import template
```

but it failed.

Comment: Personally, I gave up on using relative imports a long time ago and make sure my package is on the PATH.  They just seemed more difficult when I was learning, and I've never looked back.  That being said it, does not answer your question.  I'll do that below :)

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a touchy thing for Python.  What you are trying to do with template.py is more apt for a second package for common stuff. Just put MyDev on your [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).

So I think you would have a better time with:

```
MyDev/
  common/
    myutils.py
  solutions/
    solution1.py
    solution2.py
```

And in solution1:

```
from common.myutils import awesome_func
```

And this may explain as to why it is not working for you:

[How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

[PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) also has some good style guidelines for using imports.  Basically, in my own words, unless you are developing a large package for the community where complexity is neccesesary and imports start to get overly verbose absolute imports are the way to go.

A good example of a code base that does use relative imports is [SQLAlchemy](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/a8efeb6c052330b7b8d44960132d638b08d42d18/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py?at=master).

Answer (score 0):

You might do the following:
`import sys`
and then: `sys.path.append('../')`
If you import `template` now, it should work.